# Invoking properites of a class in Typescript without defining a model class(typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

I am working in Angular 4 with .NET Core. I am passing data from server(oracle) to client side by using web API.

Is there any way by which I can pass the data (using get/post or any other way) without creating a model class? The problem with defining structure for our entities is that we have huge data (many table with many columns) and manually defining all the entities will be very time consuming.
Dataflow is somewhat like this:

Model.cs->Controller.cs->Service.ts->Model.ts->Component.ts->component.html

I want to get rid of model.ts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare a type. You can just subscribe to your api response like this in your component.ts:

```
myGetSomeDataResponse: any;
objectKeys = [];
...
this.myService.getSomeData().subscribe(response => {
   this.myGetSomeDataResponse = response;
   this.objectKeys = Object.keys(this.myGetSomeDataResponse);
});
```

In your component's html:

```
<p *ngFor="let property of objectKeys">{{myGetSomeDataResponse[property]}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you but what if I don't know the names of these properties (myGetSomeDataResponse.property1, myGetSomeDataResponse.property2). Is there any way by which I can iterate through the loop using myGetSomeDataResponse but without knowing properties names?. Please see my below response for detailed version.

Comment: I've updated my answer to get the property keys for the object, and then looping through those unknown property keys

Answer (score 0):

```
May be, I was not clear with my question. What if I don't know the properties names of my entity? Is there any way to access these properties without using their names so instead of 

<p>myGetSomeDataResponse.property1</p>
<p>myGetSomeDataResponse.property2</p>

I would like to do something like 

  <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let AgeBandTableData of myGetSomeDataResponse">
            <td>{{AgeBandTableData.PolicyNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{AgeBandTableData.EffectiveDate}}</td>
            <td>{{AgeBandTableData.PolicyStatus}}</td>
            <td>{{AgeBandTableData.PlanName}}</td>
            <td>{{AgeBandTableData.Group}}</td>
            <td><button type="button">Modify</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

but without using these property names (PolicyNumber, EffectiveDate etc)
```